# Is there a public API for when a Rush Hour is on going?

Tags: nest-api

I noticed today my Nest thermostat showed a yellow leaf-like symbol during a [rush hour](https://nest.com/support/article/What-is-Rush-Hour-Rewards). Is there a way to do a similar call on a `Thermostat` object like `getHasLeaf()` to determine if this is currently showing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is at the structure level and it is called `peak_period_start_time` and `peak_period_end_time`

https://developers.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#peakperiodstarttime

Comment: there seems to be two copies of `peak_period_start_time` and `peak_period_end_time`. What are the differences? I noticed one requires an energy permission.

Comment: After spending some time with this, I think the API is poorly designed. While it's useful to know the start and end time in some cases, without a `structure.getTime()` method or something, it's difficult to keep a client in sync accurately because their clocks could be off. I wish there was a method like the `thermostat.hasLeaf()` to know for sure if there is a rush hour going on at that exact moment.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Everything is scheduled in server time which is rarely "off"

Comment: Sure. But on the client, how do I check if the RHR event is going on? I check the time and see if it falls in the server's peak start/end. But the client and server will not have perfectly synced clocks. Could be off a minute or 2.

Comment: RHR events are typically scheduled hours in advance and not at the start time.

Comment: Perhaps I'm nit-picking. Did you see my first question ^^ ? There seems to be two copies of `peak_period_start_time` and `peak_period_end_time`. What are the differences? I noticed one requires an energy permission.